# Anode potectial in industrial electroplation operation

Tags: grounding

I am modeling a large (physically 125' x 12' x18") electroplating line.

The line has a common anode (industrial plain carbon steel 1 x 1-1/2" x 1/4" floor grate) with multiple pairs of rectifiers that provide current to cathode conductors that support the product as it is transported through the operation .

The rectifiers provide individually up to 12,500 amps each through a combination of copper buss and flexible 2-1/2" OFHC connectors.

I have completely to my satisfaction and to readings taken during production modeled the IR drops along the cathode conductors and in the product being electroplated.

My question relates to the andoe side of the process. Because the rectifiers 'float' essentially up to the location where they are either 'commoned' together along the 125' length or where the first point in the circuit where they contact 'tank potential' (tank sits on the 'ground' and is steel).

Each of the individual rectifiers has a single output shunt which is used by the SCR fire circuit to meet set current value. Voltage varies to meet current.

So essentially each rectifier is a source of electrons, and the desired outcome is for the electrons to plate the metallic species in solution onto the product in a uniform and repeatible 'controlled' process 24/7/365.

Now enter reality.

is the anode grate reasonably to be expected to be at 'zero potential' - i.e. Do electrons that have participitated in plating process return to a ground state such that when they 'go to' the grounded anode grate they see 0V?

Or in the same way that on the cathode side there is an IR drop caused by the liner/positional resistance and the high currents. BTW the plating process is a non-linear electron sink which I am modeling as a function of concentration, activity, and chemicals.

Maybe my question is like asking on a power distribution AC utility line is the nutral leg always at zero along its multiple-mile length?

Thank you

Hope I have provided sufficient context and detail for replies.

Also there are 22 rectifiers , each two are paired and supply power to cathode conductors through different length conductors - i have this modeled and results in a potential difference across the product being processed.

Comment: Usually one wouldn't run 12kA current down a 125 foot tank, but would use higher AC voltage and transformers (not just rectifiers) to step the current up at the point-of-load.  Is that the case here?    All wire has I*R voltage losses, but low AC distribution current at high voltage keeps those losses low.

Answer (score 0):

The anode, the steel, may be a single-point connection to the rectifiers; in that case the furtherest point of the anode will have *large* voltage drops compared to the region nearest the (shared) rectifier connection.

Or the rectifiers may individually connect along the 120 feet anode, in a distributed manner, ensuring a rather uniform "ground" because the current mostly flows locally.